# Why do my web logs not correspond with the number of clicks from adwords?

Tags: analytics, google-ads

I set up a small site a while back and I've never used Adwords before so I thought I'd give it a spin. Basically the problem is that on a given day Google might report that I have had my ad clicked 50 times. However when I look at my web logs I only see 14 requests to "/" (which is where I have the campaign pointed to) and only 2 of those requests has google.com as the referrer. Why might this be? I would expect to see closer to 50 requests to "/" with google.com as the referrer.

I already read https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2375399

Answer (score 1):

All campaigns should expect some drop off.  There is a similar question here about stats compared to Google Analytics:  [Discrepancies between visits recorded in analytics and clicks reported in AdWords](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55009/discrepancies-between-visits-recorded-in-analytics-and-clicks-reported-in-adword)  You won't have many of the issues described there for JavaScript disabled or the GA tracker not being included.  But there are still some potential causes:

- Some users manage to click and then back out after the time it was tracked but before it hits your server.
- Website downtime is another case in which ads will send tracked visitors that never reach your site.
- A third possibility is the potential of fraud.   Both the advertising network and any sites on which the ads appear have incentive to artificially increase clicks for which you pay.  See [How can I prevent invalid clicks on my AdWords campaigns?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8252/how-can-i-prevent-invalid-clicks-on-my-adwords-campaigns)

14/50 (72%) drop off is very high.  Most campaigns should expect a 10%-20% 
between clicks measured through the advertiser compared to server log stats.

Google has a document that can help you with this problem entitled [How can you help prevent invalid traffic?](https://www.google.com/ads/adtrafficquality/advertisers.html) It has a bunch of details about tracking and reporting that are important for understanding traffic you never received.

Ultimately you can:

- Complain to Google.  [This page](https://www.google.com/ads/adtrafficquality/advertisers.html) has instructions for requesting an invalid traffic investigation.
- Stop using Google AdWords.
- Accept the high drop of rate and adjust the amount you are willing to pay per click accordingly.
- Move to a [cost per action (CPA)](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6268632?hl=en) bidding model.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons could be that you site is not accessible. I.e. people click (and it's counted), but the page is not loaded.

Comment: That's possible, however the backend app server error log and the nginx server error log are empty. Making me skeptical this is the issue.